# DropDowns for Department and TeamMemebrs

Tags: dropdown, cascading-dropdown

I have two fields:  one "Department" and two "Team Member".

When I select say "Claims Department" from the first drop down I would like the second drop down to be populated with the "TeamMember" of only the "Claims Department".

I would like to achieve this with 1 or 2 SharePoint lists due to easy editing due to turnover and easy training hand off from IT.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I would like to stay away from InfoPath.

Comment: *** like to stay away from InfoPath .... no InfoPath please

Comment: These are what are known as Cascading dropdowns. You can use SPServices or REST api to achieve this. REST api is recommended though. http://www.markrackley.net/2014/05/20/cascading-drop-down-lists-in-sharepoint-office-365-using-rest/

Comment: Where do you want to place the cascading dropdowns? In any list forms? or on some web part page through custom web parts? Please help me to help you...

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPServices, following function can help you.

```
SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns()
```

You can have more information [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using).